# Chromedriver open a blank page instead of the target website in selenium web driver and browser closes automatically

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testing, webdriver-manager

`Chromedriver` opens a blank page instead of the target website in selenium web driver and then closes automatically. I get this error:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError..
```

it happens for open any site. example:

```
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
```

**Version 92.0.4515.159 32** bit chrome browsers and corresponding same version **chromedriver.exe on Win10**...

webdrivermanager version tried - 3.2 to latest as well.

```
Selenium 3.14.0
TestNG 6.11
```

Also tried downgrading browser and corresponding chrome driver to lower versions **like 91** did not help

My automation suite was working week back. What could be the issue?

Comment: try to clear you project and then maven build and maven test should do the job.

Comment: Thanks @cruisepandey, I cleaned the project file-Invalidate caches / restart.., deleted target directory and rebuild the project.. right clicked on testng.xml and run, it did not help, launched blank browser and closes. However I tried executing from command prompt with mvn clean install, it works fine.. Looks something wrong on intellij with clean and rebuild?

Comment: Issue while executing from Intellij ...